# Thread Freeze while reading serial port

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, queue

I am trying to read from a serial port and put the data in a queue.

I have a thread to read from this queue and do some calculation on the data. the name of the thread is: QueueThread

how ever, 1 of threads freezes.

here is my code:

```
private void init()
{
    _sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Sp_DataReceived);
    QueueThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(queueThread));
    QueueThread.IsBackground = true;
    QueueThread.Start();
}


private void Sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    spd.data = new byte[(sender as SerialPort).BytesToRead]; // get the bytes to read                                                    
    (sender as SerialPort).Read(spd.data, 0, (sender as SerialPort).BytesToRead);

    _mySerialPortData.ComName = _sp.PortName;
    _mySerialPortData.data = spd.data;
    _mySerialPortData.dt = DateTime.Now;

    lock (_message)
    {
        _queueSerialData.Enqueue(_mySerialPortData);                            
    }
}



private void queueThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        //lock (_message)
        //{
        int queuecnt = _queueSerialData.Count;
            if (queuecnt > 0)
            {

                SerialPortData spdq1 = new SerialPortData();
                lock (_queueSerialData)
                {
                    spdq1 = _queueSerialData.Dequeue();
                }

                if (spdq1.data[0] == 0x0D) // is it the start of the 0x0D                                                
                {

                    if (spdq1.data.Length < 2)
                    {
                        _queueSerialData.Enqueue(spdq1);
                        break;
                    }

                    int x = Int32.Parse(spdq1.data[1].ToString()); //data[1] is the length of the message.                         
                    x = x + 2; //the +2 is for include the STM and the EOM


                    if (spdq1.data.Length > x) // does the data that has been recieived 
                    {
                        if (spdq1.data[x] == 0x0A) //found 0x0A meesage  
                        {
                            if (x == spdq1.data.Length - 1) // if the message  is the exact length.
                            {
                                Newspdq1 = spdq1;
                                _queueSerialDataFinal.Enqueue(Newspdq1);
                            }
                            else //  if message is not the exact length there is more message.
                            {
                                Newspdq1 = new SerialPortData();
                                Newspdq1.ComName = spdq1.ComName;
                                Newspdq1.dt = spdq1.dt;
                                Newspdq1.data = new byte[x + 1];

                                for (int j = 0; j < x + 1; j++)
                                {
                                    Newspdq1.data[j] = spd.data[j];
                                }
                                lock (_queueSerialDataFinal)
                                {
                                    _queueSerialDataFinal.Enqueue(Newspdq1); // this is a real message
                                }

                                int y = Int32.Parse(spdq1.data[x + 2].ToString()); //x+2 is the length of the next message
                                y = y + 2; //the +2 is for include the STM and the EOM


                                if (spdq1.data[spdq1.data.Length - 1] == 0x0A) // the length of the secound  message is exactly the end of the messages
                                {
                                    Newspdq1 = new SerialPortData();
                                    Newspdq1.ComName = spdq1.ComName;
                                    Newspdq1.dt = spdq1.dt;
                                    Newspdq1.data = new byte[y + 1];

                                    for (int j = x + 1; j < spdq1.data.Length; j++)
                                    {
                                        Newspdq1.data[j - x - 1] = spd.data[j];
                                        lock (_queueSerialDataFinal)
                                        {
                                            _queueSerialDataFinal.Enqueue(Newspdq1);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    _queueSerialData.Enqueue(spdq1);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        }

                        else // the message doesn'e end with EOM 
                        {
                            _queueSerialData.Enqueue(spdq1);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _queueSerialData.Enqueue(spdq1);
                    break;
                }
               //  }

            }

            if (_queueSerialData2.Count > 0)
            {
                lock (_queueSerialData2)
                {
                }

            }


            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
     //  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you observe the freeze while debugging? If so, when the freeze occurs try to go in VS to menu / DEBUG / Break All. The use the menu / DEBUG / Windows / Threads. That in combination with viewing the call stack may give you some info where is the code frozen.

Comment: I cannot debug the freeze. the :"QueueThread" freeze. other threads continue such as GUI

Comment: Maybe adding Debug.WriteLine statements in strategic places will help. That is the poor's man solution but every once in a while I get to do that...

Comment: Have you tried adding a `ReadTimeout` to the `SerialPort` I had freezing behaviour usually in the reading and writing operations